# How to design a Ajax PUT request and controller that works?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, request, put

I am developing an asp.net web api solution, but can't get a "PUT" request in Jquery to work. I tried all what is written about the subject but no luck so far.

```js
function insertstopcode(id) {
    var insert = {};

    insert.stopcause = $("#DropDownList4").val(); 
    insert.id = $("#DropDownList5").val();

    alert(insert.id)
    alert(insert.stopcause)

    $.ajax({
        type:'PUT',
        url: 'http://localhost:52059/api/stop/'+insert.id,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: JSON.stringify(insert),
        contentType: "Application/json;charset=utf-8",
        succes: function (data) {
        alert('Stopcode er registreret..')
            }
       })
}
```

My controller looks like:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/stop/{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult Put(int id)
{
    using (testdatabseEntities1 nd = new testdatabseEntities1())
    {
        var bb = nd.BI_table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
        return Ok(bb);
    }
}
```

Comment: Update your controller method like this: `public void Put(int id, [FromBody] object value)`

Comment: What part isn't working? Is the browser not sending a request, or is the application not handling it? (You can see if the browser is making a request in the debugger most browsers have - just press F12 when you're in your browser to open it.)

Comment: Always add an error method to an Ajax request so you know that the problem is with the Ajax call.

Comment: I changed my controller to: [HttpPut]
        [Route("api/stop/{id:int}")]
        public void Put(int id,[FromBody] object value) 
        {
            using (testdatabseEntities1 nd = new testdatabseEntities1())
            {
                var bb = nd.BI_table.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
                
            }
        }

Comment: I added an error method :error: function(error){
            alert(error);
        },  But no error came

Comment: Thanks...I found the solution after two long days.....